# verification using Questasim

Tags: questasim

I am trying to verify my design in Questasim and the design is in VHDL. I am using Makefile. The command is

```
vcom -93 -work $(work) $(RTL) $(SVTB1) $(SVTB)
```

It is invoking VHDL compiler, but it is not displaying the master_driver signals.
Can anybody tell the solution?

Comment: You would need to post the entire makefile for us to know what is wrong

Comment: comp0:
 vlog -work $(work) $(RTL) $(INC) $(SVTB1) $(SVTB)
comp1: 
 vcom -93 -mixedsvvh -work $(work) $(RTL) $(SVTB1) $(SVTB)

Comment: @noobuntu                                                                                                    is there any command for compiling VHDL as well as SV files together?

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution but I don't know whether it's a perfect one.
The solution to my question is that divide SV and VHDL codes in two different folders and compile them separately. But the work folder should be same.